# Electron - IPC - sending data between windows

Tags: ipc, electron

In the main process, I create a window called `mainWindow`. On a button click, I create a new `browserWindow` called `notesWindow`.

What I want to do is send data from `notesWindow` to `mainWindow`

What I did is used IPC send to first send the data from `notesWindow` to the main process, retrieve the data on the main process, then send that data to `mainWindow`, but `mainWindow` is unable to receive the sender event. Sending data to the main process works fine, but from the main process to browserWindow doesn't seem to work.

> main.js

```
const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

ipcMain.on('notes', function(event, data) {
      console.log(data) // this properly shows the data
      event.sender.send('notes2', data);
});
```

> noteWindow.js

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipcRenderer.send('notes', "new note");
```

> mainWindow.js

```
const ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
ipcRenderer.on('notes2', function(event, data) {
    // this function never gets called
    console.log(data);
});
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mainWindow` is not able to receive the event because it is not getting sent to it. The `events.sender.send()` code in `main.js` will send the data back to whoever sent the `notes` event, which in this case is the `noteWindow`. So the `notes2` event is getting sent back to `noteWindow` instead of `mainWindow`.

To send the `notes2` event to `mainWindow`, check out [**`webContents.send()`**](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-contents/#contentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-). This allows the main process to send data via events to a specific window. After some modifications to `main.js` it would look similar to this:

```
ipcMain.on('notes', function(event, data) {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('notes2', data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using webContents.send before but was unable to get it to work.

`Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'webContents' of undefined`

I made the mainWindow like this
`let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({...})`

so not sure why mainWindow is undefined :S

Comment: Interesting. Placing it into the `app.on('ready', createWindows)` allows this to work. So I'm marking your answer as correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @harmonic , i have this problem, but i cannot fix it. how can i fix it?

Comment: the error i'm getting is `cannot read property "sender" of undefined`, but only on windows 10...

Comment: I answer this question with example.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103016/how-can-send-and-get-data-beteen-main-js-and-html-js-in-election/69103017#69103017

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to setup ipc hub on `main.js`. Here is how I would do it.

The key here is that if you want to have a direct ipc talk between `renderer` their need to know each other `getCurrentWebContents().id`.

## Step 1: Create a main window global object

> main.js

```js
function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(...);

    global.mainWindow = mainWindow;

    ...
}
```

## Step 2: Send data to main window (and receive)

> noteWindow.js

```js
const ipc = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
ipc.sendTo(
          getGlobal("mainWindow").webContents.id,
          "ChannelForMainWindow",
          data,
          web_component.id // for main window to send back
        );
```

> mainWindow.js

```js
ipc.on("ChannelForMainWindow", (e, data, web_component_id) => {
    // do something
});
```

## (Optional) Step 3: Send data back (and receive as well)

> noteWindow.js

let's add listener for main window reply (if any)

```js
const ipc = require("electron").ipcRenderer;

ipc.on("ChannelForNoteWindow", e => {
    ...
});

ipc.sendTo(
          getGlobal("mainWindow").webContents.id,
          "ChannelForMainWindow",
          data,
          web_component.id // for main window to send back
        );
```

> mainWindow.js

```js
ipc.on("ChannelForMainWindow", (e, data, web_component_id) => {
    // do something

    //send data back
    ipc.sendTo(web_component_id, "ChannelForNoteWindow");
});
```

Comment: This is the better.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69103016/how-can-send-and-get-data-beteen-main-js-and-html-js-in-election/69103017#69103017