# How to pass a variable from one HTML window to another in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, electron

I am creating an Electron Desktop App and I am struggling with what might be a very simple concept. Let's say I have two HTML pages (we'll call this `foo.html` and `bar.html`).
`foo.html` is the initial page in my program and once the user clicks the submit or next button a new window is spawned (on top of `foo.html`) and shows the content of `bar.html`. 
Some values are produced and visualized and presented to the user in this `bar.html`. At this point both pages are open and once the user closes `bar.html` I want to pass some values from this page and display it in a text field or a table in my `foo.html`. 
I am confused on how to approach this problem. Essentially how do I pass back a value to an HTML page which has already been rendered?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: see if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486438/electron-ipc-sending-data-between-windows

Answer (score 1):

You need to use IPC which is used to communicate between two processes. In your case, a main window and a child window.

Refer to this documentation,
[ipcMain Documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)

The main window (foo.html) acts as the Main process. Above documentation shows how to send the message you want.

The child window (bar.html) acts as the Renderer process. Which is spawned by the Main process (foo.html).
Refer this documentation on how to receive the sent message, [ipcRenderer Documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer)

You will also need to read about Parent and Child windows, in your case foo.html and bar.html respectively.

[BrowserWindow Documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#parent-and-child-windows)