# How can send and get data beteen Main.js and html.js in Election

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

How can send data with `ipcRenderer` in Electron?
I use this code but dose not work well. I can not send data to notes2 from **main.js** to **index.html**

> In Main.js

```
   ipcMain.on('notes', function(event, data) {
      console.log('notes: ', data)
      win.webContents.send('notes2', "dddddddddddddd");
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

> Main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')
let mainWindow;
/**
 * Create a new window
 */
const createWindow = () => {
   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      /** Enable node integration */
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });

  /** Open devTools */
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  /** Load the index.html page */
     mainWindow.loadURL(url.format ({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
   }))
};

/**
 * Initialize the application
 */
 
const init = () => {
  /** Create app window */
  createWindow();

  /** Define channel name and message */
  const CHANNEL_NAME = 'main';
  const MESSAGE = 'tick';
    ipcMain.on(CHANNEL_NAME, (event, data) => {
    /** Show the request data */
    console.log(data);
      mainWindow.webContents.send(CHANNEL_NAME, "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
    /** Send a response for a synchronous request */
    event.returnValue = 'pong';
  });
  /** Send message every one second */
  
  setInterval(() => {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('another', MESSAGE);
  }, 1000);
  

  
};

/**
 * Run the app
 */
app.on('ready', init);
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IPC test app</title>

    <script>
        const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

        /** Define channel name */
        const CHANNEL_NAME = 'main';

        /** Create a processor for a button's click event */
        const clickButton = () => {
          /** Message to be sent */
          let message = 'ping';

          /** Show response for a sync IPC request */
          console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync(CHANNEL_NAME, message));
        }
        
        
    /** Add IPC event listener */
      ipcRenderer.on(CHANNEL_NAME, (event, data) => {   
        console.log('hiiiiiiii ' , data);
      });
      
        /** Add IPC event listener */
      ipcRenderer.on('another', (event, data) => {  
        console.log('hello  : ' , data);
      });
      
      
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="clickButton()">Press me</button>
</body>
</html>
```